# "may not only be" or "may not be only"

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, grammaticality-in-context

Which one of the two is correct?

> Doing something may not only be a personal decision, but also a
>   business decision

Or

> Doing something may not be only a personal decision, but also a
>   business decision

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first sentence is correct, because the construct is "not only ... but also", so the verb can not be placed between "not" and "only".

For a more detailed explanation of the parallelism construct you can read [this](https://www.grammarly.com/blog/parallelism-with-not-only-but-also/) and you can see more examples [here](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/word-order-and-focus/not-only-but-also).

Answer (score 0):

If we talk about the scenario which you've given above, first one sounds correct to me. As it is **not only but also** kind of a sentence. I hope you are clear with what **not only but also** is. And of course, if it's just about **may not only be** and **may not be only**, both are correct. Depending on which one sounds good to you, you can choose one over the other. I would always go with **may not only be**.